# Align both equations and condition statements between case environments

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, cases

I have two cases environments below one another, which I would like to align around the = sign (which I could do), but also that the conditional statements be aligned across systems.

More specifically, I have the following code:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{align}
    \pi_i &=
       \begin{cases}
            a - b - c + (\frac{a}{b}) c,  &\text{if either}\; x \; \text{or}\; y\; \text{is reached} \\
            0,  &\text{otherwise} 
    \end{cases}\\
    \pi_j &=
       \begin{cases}
            a - d, &\text{if}\;  z\; \text{is reached} \\
            0, &\text{otherwise} 
    \end{cases}
\end{align}
```

The output obtained is:

[image]

However, I would like the four "if..." and "otherwise" statements to also be aligned.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eqparbox`. I define an `\eqmathbox` command that takes as arguments an arbitrary label (it should be different per usage) and the formula to be typeset.

Only the longer formulas needs to be in `\eqmathbox`, but using also `\eqmathbox{A}{0,}` would do the same.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2]{% #1 = label, #2 = body
  \eqmakebox[#1][l]{$#2$}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \pi_i &=
  \begin{cases}
  \eqmathbox{A}{a - b - c + (\frac{a}{b}) c,}  & \text{if either $x$ or $y$ is reached} \\
  0,                                           & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\\
  \pi_j &=
  \begin{cases}
  \eqmathbox{A}{a - d,} & \text{if $z$ is reached} \\
  0,                    & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

You need two runs (initially) to get the same widths.

[image]

Note the simpler way to set the textual conditions. Even simpler if you use `mathtools` and `cases*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2]{% #1 = label, #2 = body
  \eqmakebox[#1][l]{$#2$}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \pi_i &=
  \begin{cases*}
  \eqmathbox{A}{a - b - c + (\frac{a}{b}) c,}  & if either $x$ or $y$ is reached \\
  0,                                           & otherwise
  \end{cases*}
\\
  \pi_j &=
  \begin{cases*}
  \eqmathbox{A}{a - d,} & if $z$ is reached \\
  0,                    & otherwise 
  \end{cases*}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution employs a suitably defined `\parbox` to encase one of the cases in the second equation. The width of the `\parbox` is set to `$a - b - c + (\frac{a}{b}) c,$`, i.e., the larger of the two possibilities in the first equation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align' and 'cases' environments and '\text' macro

\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{$a - b - c + (\frac{a}{b}) c,$} % set width of \parbox
\newcommand\mybox[1]{\parbox{\mylen}{$#1$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\pi_i &=
  \begin{cases}
  a - b - c + (\frac{a}{b}) c, &\text{if either $x$ or $y$ is reached} \\
  0,                           &\text{otherwise} 
  \end{cases}\\
\pi_j &=
  \begin{cases}
  \mybox{a - d,} &\text{if $z$ is reached} \\
  0,     &\text{otherwise} 
  \end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `\parbox` instead of the more natural `\makebox` with left alignment?

Comment: Thank you @Mico. This solution works for the simple case in the example, but should there be more systems of equations with cases to be aligned (as is the case in my paper) then the accepted solution above provides more flexibility as it doesn't require to specify a fixed width of the \parbox.

Comment: @orpr0 - If the question changes, the answer should change too. Sure thing.